# Best srvany.exe for Windows XP and Windows 7?

Tags: windows, software-rec, services

What is the best program to use on windows XP and Windows 7 to do what srvany.exe does on windows NT (run a process as a service)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`srvany`, of course.

Windows XP and 7 *are* NT, and the `srvany` from [Windows 2003 ResKit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) works just fine on them.

Answer (score 6):

There is NSSM http://iain.cx/src/nssm/

Answer (score 4):

Windows comes with the `SC.exe` tool which allows you to directly create and modify services.

Simply go to an elevated Command Prompt and type:

> `sc.exe create <Service Name> binPath= <Path> DisplayName= <name>`

For example, to create a (useless) notepad service, you could use:

> `sc.exe create MyNotepadService binPath= "C:\windows\notepad.exe" DisplayName= "My notepad Service"`

(Please note, spacing after the equals and before the value is important)

You can then start the service from the command prompt using `SC start <Service Name>` or through the services section of `Computer Management`.

Comment: If the exe doesn't respond to service commands, then I believe it will not work with sc. For example cmd.exe won't run at all unless you set it as interactive, which is depreciated in vista and 7 and doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

[FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com/). You have to pay for it but it has a lot of features and works well.