# Does srvany.exe work for windows 7

Tags: windows, services

after reading this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890
i was wondering does this utility also works in `windows 7`.

All i want is to run `VLC player` and start playing a song at each reboot. SO basically i want to run `<<vlc.exe song-path>>`.

Please tell me how can i do this?

Does anyone know who can i add a simple executable binary to run as NT service in windows 7. This is very important for me to know otherwise i will be a failure.

Comment: I believe srvany.exe works on Windows 7, but you might like to consider NSSM instead: http://nssm.cc/

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/146141/best-srvany-exe-for-windows-xp-and-windows-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `srvany` may work on Windows 7, but it I doubt that a service in Windows 7 has access to the sound out channel.

I would solve this problem with either a scheduled task, triggered on log on, or using an entry in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Those are fully supported solutions that will work on Windows 7.