# Script to alert removing a usb drive before logging off

Tags: windows-7, script, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-12.04

I keep leaving my usb drives connected to the lab machines of my dept.So far I have been lucky to always find it in the lost and found but not having it when you need it gets a bit irritating.

Is there a utility/script available that will prompt me to remove it before I log off ?
I am looking for solution for doing this both in Windows and Linux.
Any pointers on how to go about writing one ?

Comment: occupancy sensor + programming language automation - MatLab, Labview, C, C++,JAVA

Comment: I suggest posting separate questions for each OS, otherwise it becomes difficult to accept answers unless someone is able to satisfy all your OS requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A simple VBScript to check for presence of removable devices would look like this:

```
boolDeviceFound = False
strComputer = InputBox("Enter the name of the computer to search for USB devices:")
strComputer = Trim(strComputer)
If LenB(strComputer) = 0 Then
    strComputer = "."
End If

'Query the WMI service for the computer name
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

'Display the connected computer
WScript.Echo "You have successfully connected to computer " & strComputer

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE Description = 'Removable Disk'")
For Each objItem in colItems
    WScript.Echo "The computer " & strComputer & " has a removable USB drive connected with drive letter: " & objItem.Name
    WScript.Echo "Please remove this device from " & strComputer & " to comply with Lab policies!"
    boolDeviceFound = True
Next

If boolDeviceFound = False Then
    WScript.Echo "No USB devices found!"
End If
```

If you save it as something like **DetectUSB.vbs**, it can be executed from the command line or a batch file using `wscript DetectUSB.vbs`. Something similar can be written using PowerShell as well, and the batch file/PS script can be [set as a logoff script](https://superuser.com/a/548196/138343). Only problem is, do you even have sufficient rights on the lab PC(s) to install logoff scripts?

Comment: If the scripts do work, the lab admin might install it on the machines since a lot of people seem to be leaving their usbs on the machines